# why os.read() in python works correctly only after adding specific value for time.sleep()?

Tags: python, linux, process, sleep

Could anyone help to understand why there is a difference between the outputs of the `code block 1` and the `code block 2`? I understand that there is some time needed to process the input (is this so?), however how to determine this time and does it depend on a hardware, etc? Is this possible to escape the usage of `time.sleep()`? Environment: Python3.6.9, Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, running inside the docker container that is hosted on WSL 2.

```
import os, pty, subprocess, time


#-------------code block 1--------
(pid, fd) = pty.fork()
if(pid == 0):
    subprocess.run('/bin/bash')
else:
    print('result of the block 1')
    os.write(fd, 'cd /home\n'.encode())
    print(os.read(fd,1024))
    os.write(fd, 'l'.encode())
    print(os.read(fd,1024))
    os.write(fd, 's'.encode())
    print(os.read(fd,1024))
    os.write(fd, '\n'.encode())
    time.sleep(0.005)
    print(os.read(fd,1024))
#-------------code block 1--------


#-------------code block 2--------
(pid, fd) = pty.fork()
if(pid == 0):
    subprocess.run('/bin/bash')
else:
    print('result of the block 2')
    os.write(fd, 'cd /home\n'.encode())
    print(os.read(fd,1024))
    os.write(fd, 'l'.encode())
    print(os.read(fd,1024))
    os.write(fd, 's'.encode())
    print(os.read(fd,1024))
    os.write(fd, '\n'.encode())
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print(os.read(fd,1024))
#-------------code block 2--------
```

the output:

```
result of the block 1
b'cd /home\r\n'
b'l'
b's'
b'\r\n'
result of the block 2
b'cd /home\r\n'
b'l'
b's'
b'\r\n\x1b]0;root@a1625893bf1b: /home/app\x07root@a1625893bf1b:/home/app# cd /home\r\n\x1b]0;root@a1625893bf1b: /home\x07root@a1625893bf1b:/home# ls\r\n\x1b[0m\x1b[01;34mapp\x1b[0m\r\n\x1b]0;root@a1625893bf1b: /home\x07root@a1625893bf1b:/home# '
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
 { printf 'foo'; sleep 1; printf 'bar\n'; } |
    python3 -c 'import os, time; time.sleep(0.5); print(os.read(0, 1024))'
```

This prints `foo`. If you change the `time.sleep` to 1.5, it'll print `foobar`.

This happens because the input is a stream, and will return whatever's currently been added to the stream since the last time you read from it. The pty keeps being written to in small text chunks, so if you read immediately, you'll only get a few of those. If you wait longer, more will have been queued up and so the following `read` call returns more data.

You are treating your pty as a call&response API where you hope to write some data and read the result. This fundamentally does not work.

It's instead an infinite, bidirectional stream, and it's your responsibility to read, segment, and make sense of any data you receive regardless of how many or few `read` calls it's split over.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - your example is nice for understanding, is there any pattern to implement a call&response API based on os.write/read?

Comment: If you need to run multiple commands in the same session and split up the output between them, the typical approach used by CI systems is to rig the shell to output a recognizable token between commands or otherwise signal to your application that the command is done, and live with the fact that any asynchronous output will be misclassified. This can be done e.g. by configuring the shell prompt, or by wrapping the shell command.

Comment: Thanks for ideas, could you, please, recommend a couple of links where I can read more about this?